# I'm installing Ubuntu, and all I see is a spinning wheel. What could be the problem?

Tags: 14.04

I'm installing Ubuntu fit the first time ever. I decided to do it alongside my Windows 7 installation.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB stick. Everything started fine, but after a while there's nothing on the screen but a spinning wheel. I've been watching it now for more than 15 minutes :

[image: spin-wheel]

Do I have to worry? And in case there is a problem, how to fix it? Can I just reboot the computer and start over again?

**UPDATE**

The answer is much more silly than I thought. Apparently, the USB stick (physically) moved at some point during the install process and interrupted it.

As mentioned in the comments, all I had to do was to reboot the system and restart the installation all over again. It went smoothly. It even automatically detected how much space I assigned to each partition.

I hope this helps any one in the future.

Comment: Check your USB drive's .iso image? Restarting is not a bad idea...it should not be stuck for so long(i haven't experienced such a long wait)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Ashu thanks! Your comment guided me to the right path. Could you please repost it as an answer so that I can mark correct?

Comment: @ahmed. Glad to know. did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your USB drive's .iso image. Sometimes due to high load the download is impacted and it might have been corrupted.
You can make use of [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create the bootable USB. Could be issue with the USB drive also.
Restarting is not a bad idea...it should not be stuck for so long(i haven't experienced such a long wait)

Answer (score 2):

check the ISO image you downloaded, it could've gotten corrupted by some windows viruses while writing it to a USB flash and it is also good and not harmful to restart the process again and also  [checking the md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the ISO is important